# Serial port open returning EAGAIN

Tags: c++, linux, serial-port

I'm getting an EAGAIN error right after opening my serial port. The code is used in a shared library and called by Python code.

I know the port (/dev/ttyUSB0) is good. I used the same port to communicate directly with Python (PySerial) and it is working fine. In that case, my device answers.

But when the code below is called from ctypes (Python)... I get the EAGAIN error.

```
ERROR_CODES SerialPortLinux::openCommunication() {
    ERROR_CODES error_code;
    hComm = open(port_name.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);

    error_code = getPortErrorCode();
    if (error_code == ERROR_CODES::SUCCESS) {
        ...
    } else {
        close(hComm);
    }
    return error_code;
}


ERROR_CODES SerialPortLinux::getPortErrorCode(){
    ERROR_CODES error_code;
    auto error_number = errno;
    switch(error_number){
        ...
    }
}
```

Is there a configuration to be done prior to getting the handle?
Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `errno` after a **successful** call to any POSIX system function is unspecified, at least per Single Unix Specification v6. You should see if `open()` was successful (i.e. returned non-negative handle), and analyze `errno` only if `open()` failed.

So, your code should be:

```
ERROR_CODES SerialPortLinux::openCommunication()
{
    ERROR_CODES error_code;
    hComm = open(port_name.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);
    if (hComm == -1)
    {
        error_code = getPortErrorCode();
        // Treat this error condition somehow
        return error_code;
    }

    return ERROR_CODES::SUCCESS;
}
```

In your particular case, I guess that the `open()` operation was successful, but you still got EAGAIN from `errno` because that value was there since the last failed operation.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, but it definitely helps. I will have a look. Thanks

Comment: @BaldDude I edited the answer to make my point explicit. I think the error code you got is a false error. The operation was successful but you've read some random value from errno.

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem, but it DOES answer the/my question as posted. I will accept the answer and continue my investigation.